# My files have disappeared, How can I recover them?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

So I get a new hard drive, pop it in my Win10 computer's external HDD bay, setup and format it, transfer all files from my previous storage drive onto the new drive, check to make sure all my files are there in the new drive which they were, format my old drive, remove the new drive from the bay and swap it inside with my old one, start my computer and low and behold all my files are gone! The files still seem to be there as my drive says it has used space.

I've tried showing hidden files and showing system files in Windows10. Nothing. I now have it connected to my Ubuntu server and patched into it using File Zilla, it did show me 2 folders that were luckily very important to me so I recovered them. Does anyone know what Windows did? And how I can reverse what happened?

I'll continue to try and recover my files myself, but I just hoped someone here would have a quick answer to my question.

Comment: P.S. - I started a game on the new drive after doing the file transfer and the game played perfectly, so I know for a fact the files are there. I think they must be hidden by some annoying Windows safety feature.

Comment: Have you tried putting the drive back in the external HDD bay?

Comment: Yes, sir, I have. Only to see the same issue. That's when I decided to put it in my server to check using FTP.

Comment: Well, sorry then. The only thing I can suggest would be a recovery program that can deal with deleted files and/or a reformatted disk.

Answer (score -1):

It seems there was an issue with me hotswapping the drives. I ended up doing a simple check disk from the "right click, properties" window and all my files were recovered just like that. I tried even using Recuva which did help in the end, but what really fixed the situation was the simple check disk.